# gevent loading failure: DLL load failed inside venv

Tags: python, gevent

I'm currently using venv and gevent inside my python environment, and I can't seem to get it to work. Here's my stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Projects\sfe-giveaways\venv\lib\site-packages\disco\cli.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gevent import monkey
  File "D:\Projects\sfe-giveaways\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I believe that I need a 32-bit version of gevent so it's compatible with venv, but I don't know how to install the 32-bit version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where would I put the wheel? Would it be outside of venv?

Comment: Sorry, I give you a python 3.7 wheel before. Please try this one: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/77/3359ffd56920e48b45a79c240664f8619167b70124f87e711a89d310c632/gevent-1.3.7-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl You can just use `pip install gevent-1.3.7-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl` to install it

Comment: I got another DLL error while trying to install the wheel with `from pyexpat import *`

Comment: I don't know what is pyexpat, maybe this is another 3rd lib. But now I'm pretty sure your can just rebuild a new venv, and run `pip install gevent` in this env. Don't copy old libs, just reinstall them. `pip` will find correctly one automatically.

Comment: problem solved. i know this sounds really stupid, but apparently i don't use venv.